# How can you submit a new word for inclusion in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an ‘official’ way to suggest a new word become part of the English language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/is-there-an-official-way-to-suggest-a-new-word-become-part-of-the-english-lang)

If I happened to have coined a few words that I find could be of practical value to the general public, how can I make a request to have it included in one of the standard dictionaries of the English language?

Comment: This is a question you should ask the editor of the dictionary you want to have your word included in. Different dictionaries will have different procedures. Though, of course, no dictionary is going to include a word just because you invented it, and nobody is going to use a word just because it's sitting in a dictionary somewhere. You don't get to decide what's of practical value to the general public. Only the general public gets to decide that. Dictionaries *follow* usage.

Comment: foampile, You might be interested in Erin McKean's work on Wordnik.com and her blog http://www.dictionaryevangelist.com/. She also gives an engaging TED talk on lexicography, which you can find at http://www.ted.com/talks/erin_mckean_redefines_the_dictionary.html

Comment: Let me guess, the word you are trying to get accepted is "foampile"? I'll start using it. Does it mean "a pile of foam"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Every time I shave, I start with a modest foampile of shaving cream.