# Which institution or regulatory body is legitimate to define a spelling reform of the english language?

Tags: pronunciation-respelling

There are many proposals to reform the English spelling, to make it more similar to its phonetic pronunciation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_reforms_of_English

But in the end, who decides whether and how to reform?

[Edit]
The Oxford university? An 'Ivy League' of language universities in the world?

Comment: Which institutions or regulatory bodies do you think exist for the English language?

Comment: All attempts are doomed, because there is no "correct" way to pronounce English. It is regional. It's been tried before... Nobody decides: dictionaries reflect established usage, as it changes with the times.

Comment: There is no official body monitoring the English language. Oxford University _Press_ publishes the Oxford English Dictionary, but that describes historical and current usage, it doesn't make the rules.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462/regulatory-bodies-and-authoritative-dictionaries-for-english) discusses regulatory bodies for English. See also [this question about adding a word to the dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/is-there-an-official-way-to-suggest-a-new-word-become-part-of-the-english-lang).

Comment: In the end, I decide: I won't have it.

Comment: In the end, as pointed out, the English language is just whatever English speakers speak. "Reforming" is not what it needs. Maybe it needs a better spelling system, but that would just lock out dialects. When you find an organization that can "reform" arithmetic, turn'em loose on grammar.

Comment: Vive la difference.